# Откуда берутся лишние лишние скобки в JSON? Python

Tags: python, json, база-данных, функции

Вот кусок кода. при запуске на каждую функцию вводится два значения.

```
 def monday():

        def first():
            shedule = {}

            lesson1 = int(input("Введите первую пару по верхней неделе: "))
            lesson2 = int(input("Введите вторую пару по нижней неделе: "))

            
            first = list(range(10830, 10859, 5)) + list(range(10900, 10959, 5))
            for i in first:
                if lesson1 == 0:
                    lesson1 = None
                if lesson2 == 0:
                    lesson2 = None

                shedule[i] = {
                    "lesson1": lesson1,
                    "lesson2": lesson2
                }
                return shedule

        def second():
            shedule = {}

            lesson1 = int(input("Введите первую пару по верхней неделе: "))
            lesson2 = int(input("Введите вторую пару по нижней неделе: "))

            
            second = list(range(11015, 11059, 5)) + list(range(11100, 11145, 5))
            for i in second:
                if lesson1 == 0:
                    lesson1 = None
                if lesson2 == 0:
                    lesson2 = None

                shedule[i] = {
                    "lesson1": lesson1,
                    "lesson2": lesson2
                }
                return shedule



        def main():

            shedule = first(), second()
            with open("data_lesson.json", "w") as file:
                json.dump(shedule, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
        main()
```

Насколько JSON должен выглядеть как:

```
{
    "11140": {
        "lesson1": "www.example.com",
        "lesson2": "www.example.com"
    }
}
```

Но при запуске откуда-то берутся квадратные скобки

```
[
    {
        "10830": {
            "lesson1": "example.com",
            "lesson2": null
        }
    },
    {
        "11015": {
            "lesson1": "example.com"
            "lesson2": null
        }
    }
]
```

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: `shedule = first(), second()` - в этой строке стоит запятая, а значит вы создаёте кортеж из двух словарей

Comment: `shedule = {**first(), **second()}` или `shedule = dict((*first.items(), *second.items()))`